# Dynamic object arguments in WF4 Activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Is it possible to use dynamic objects (extending DynamicObject) in WF4 Activity that can be used in expressions?

I get the following error messages when running a unit test that invokes an activity that had a dynamic object as a parameter.

using DynamicObject as the argument type

> System.Activities.InvalidWorkflowException : The following errors were
>   encountered while processing the workflow tree:
>   'Literal': Literal only supports value types and the
>   immutable type System.String.  The type System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
>   cannot be used as a literal. 'Legal': The private implementation of
>   activity '1: Legal' has the following validation error:   Compiler
>   error(s) encountered processing expression "deal.Region = "EMEA"".
>   'Region' is not a member of 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject'.

Using actual type as argument type

> System.Activities.InvalidWorkflowException : The following errors were
>   encountered while processing the workflow tree:
>   'Literal': Literal only supports value types and the
>   immutable type System.String.  The type
>   WorkflowTest.DealValueHelper cannot be used as a literal.
>   'Legal': The private implementation of activity '1: Legal' has the
>   following validation error:   Compiler error(s) encountered processing
>   expression "deal.Region = "EMEA"". 'Region' is not a member of
>   'WorkflowTest.DealValueHelper'.

Comment: Did Ron's post work for you? If so, please mark it as the answer for the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this absolutely works.  I've created just such an object in `Microsoft.Activities.Extensions.WorkflowArguments`.

What you are encountering is likely an error when trying to assign directly to an `InArgument` of an activity.  I wrote a blog post about this [Passing arguments to Workflow Activities (again)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/05/26/passing-arguments-to-workflow-activities-again.aspx)